# Website with a 30% non english content (70% english) can be accepted in Tribal Fusion?

Tags: advertising

I'm just wondering If a website has a 30% non English content, will the Tribal Fusion Ad Network still accepts it's application.

My website has a 30% non english content and 70% english. I don't want to submit my application because if they reject my application, i'll be waiting again for the next 6-8 months for reapplication.

This might be my 2nd time to apply to Tribal Fusion. The first time, i got rejected is  because i dont meet the 500K unique visitors /month. As of today, I am hitting the minimum unique visitors per month.

I just need to be sure and very careful. please understand... Can somebody shed some light here?

Answer (score 1):

[Here are their published requirements](http://www.tribalfusion.com/publishers/siterequirements). I see nothing about language. Nobody who isn't a representative for the company can tell you anything more than that. If you have further questions about their requirements, [contact them directly](http://www.tribalfusion.com/tfcompany/contactus).